# How to Use Nested Grid View in mvc3 using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to create a grid inside a gird.Before nesting the parent grid it is fine but when i tried nesting another gird it shows that `WebGrid.Colums` have sone invalid arguments.
I have following code

```
   <div id="lgrid" class="tablesorter">

  @{
     var grid = new WebGrid(Model.AssetDetails, rowsPerPage: 20, canSort: false, canPage: false, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "1grid");
    }
       @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "lgrid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("S.N.", format: @<text>@{count++;}@count</text>, style: "sn"),
    grid.Column("Name", format: @<text>@item.Category.CategoryTitle</text>, style: "ItemNo"),  
    grid.Column("ItemDesc", format: @<text>@item.ItemDescription</text>, style: "ItemNo"),
    grid.Column("Quantity", format: @<text>@item.Quantity</text>, style: "Quantity"),
    grid.Column("Unit", format: @<text>@item.Unit.UnitSymbol</text>, style: "Unit"),
    grid.Column("Unit Price", format: @<text>@item.UnitPriceUSD</text>, style: "UnitPrice"),
    grid.Column("ExchangeRate", format: @<text>@item.ExchangeRate</text>, style: "ExchangeRate"),
    grid.Column("NPR", format: @<text>@{NPR = (@item.UnitPriceUSD * @item.ExchangeRate);}@NPR</text>, style: "NPR"),

    grid.Column("AssetDetails", format: (item) =>
    {
        WebGrid resGrid = new WebGrid(item.AssetDetails);
        return resGrid.GetHtml(
        columns: resGrid.Columns(
        resGrid.Column("Parameters", format: (resource) =>
            {
                WebGrid resParamGrid = new WebGrid(resource.AssetDetails);
                return resParamGrid.GetHtml(
                    columns: resParamGrid.Columns(
                        resParamGrid.Column("AssetNo", format: @<text>@newasst.AssetNo</text>),
                        resParamGrid.Column("SerialNo", format: @<text>@newasst.SerialNo</text>),
                        resParamGrid.Column("ModelNo", format: @<text>@newasst.ModelNo</text>),
                        resParamGrid.Column("Remarks", format: @<text>@newasst.Remarks</text>)
                    ),
                    displayHeader: false
                );
            })
        ),
        displayHeader: false
    );
    }),

    ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formatting your code, you have some mixed up opening and closing parenthesis. Also you have some naming conflicts and too many grids.

Try like this:

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(
        Model, 
        rowsPerPage: 20, 
        canSort: false, 
        canPage: false, 
        ajaxUpdateContainerId: "1grid"
    );
}

@grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "lgrid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("S.N.", format: @<text>@{count++;}@count</text>, style: "sn"),
        grid.Column("Name", format: @<text>@item.CategoryTitle</text>, style: "ItemNo"),  
        grid.Column("ItemDesc", format: @<text>@item.ItemDescription</text>, style: "ItemNo"),
        grid.Column("Quantity", format: @<text>@item.Quantity</text>, style: "Quantity"),
        grid.Column("Unit", format: @<text>@item.UnitSymbol</text>, style: "Unit"),
        grid.Column("Unit Price", format: @<text>@item.UnitPriceUSD</text>, style: "UnitPrice"),
        grid.Column("ExchangeRate", format: @<text>@item.ExchangeRate</text>, style: "ExchangeRate"),
        grid.Column("NPR", format: @<text>@string.Format("{0:c}", item.UnitPriceUSD * item.ExchangeRate)</text>, style: "NPR"),
        grid.Column("AssetDetails", format: row =>
        {
            WebGrid resGrid = new WebGrid(row.AssetDetails);
            return resGrid.GetHtml(
                columns: resGrid.Columns(
                    resGrid.Column("AssetNo", format: @<text>@item.AssetNo</text>),
                    resGrid.Column("SerialNo", format: @<text>@item.SerialNo</text>),
                    resGrid.Column("ModelNo", format: @<text>@item.ModelNo</text>),
                    resGrid.Column("Remarks", format: @<text>@item.Remarks</text>)
                ),
                displayHeader: false
            );
        })
    )
)
```